# OFBiz Showing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in browser

Tags: ofbiz

I am new to OfBiz, and I got stuck here for 2 days.  Hope someone can help.

I am following these instructions to install OFBiz on AWS Debian.
https://ofbiz.apache.org/developers.html
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-apache-ofbiz-crm-on-debian-10/

I got all the problem resolved.

After executing `./gradlew ofbiz`, it seems the application is started, but my browser is showing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.  The curl command shows the same:

```
curl http://localhost:8443/accounting
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This is the last messages I am seeing in the terminal:

```
2022-03-09 15:15:57,134 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ConfigXMLReader               |I| controller loaded: 0.002s, 64 requests, 22 views in file:/usr/local/apache-ofbiz/specialpurpose/webpos/webapp/webpos/WEB-INF/controller.xml
2022-03-09 15:15:57,169 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceDispatcher             |I| Registering dispatcher: catalog
2022-03-09 15:15:57,169 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceContainer              |I| Created new dispatcher: catalog
2022-03-09 15:15:57,170 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ControlServlet                |I| Loading webapp [catalog], located at /usr/local/apache-ofbiz/applications/product/webapp/catalog/
2022-03-09 15:15:57,207 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceDispatcher             |I| Registering dispatcher: setup
2022-03-09 15:15:57,207 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceContainer              |I| Created new dispatcher: setup
2022-03-09 15:15:57,207 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ControlServlet                |I| Loading webapp [ofbizsetup], located at /usr/local/apache-ofbiz/applications/commonext/webapp/ofbizsetup/
2022-03-09 15:15:57,241 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ConfigXMLReader               |I| controller loaded: 0.017s, 32 requests, 15 views in file:/usr/local/apache-ofbiz/applications/commonext/webapp/ofbizsetup/WEB-INF/controller.xml
2022-03-09 15:15:57,297 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceDispatcher             |I| Registering dispatcher: ical
2022-03-09 15:15:57,297 |0.0.0.0-startStop-1  |ServiceContainer              |I| Created new dispatcher: ical
Mar 09, 2022 3:15:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 09, 2022 3:15:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 09, 2022 3:15:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Connector AJP/1.3 @ 8009 - not-secure [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol] started.
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Connector HTTP/1.1 @ 8080 - not-secure [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] started.
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Connector HTTP/1.1 @ 8443 - secure [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] started.
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Started Apache Tomcat/8.0.42
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Started container catalina-container
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Starting container birt-container
2022-03-09 15:15:57,356 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Start BIRT container
2022-03-09 15:15:57,367 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Startup BIRT platform
2022-03-09 15:15:58,888 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Create factory object
2022-03-09 15:15:58,918 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Create report engine
2022-03-09 15:15:59,080 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| BIRT supported formats: xlsx, postscript, docx, pptx, pdf, ppt, xls_spudsoft, doc, html, odp, xls, odt, ods
2022-03-09 15:15:59,080 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Started container birt-container
2022-03-09 15:15:59,740 |OFBiz-JobPoller      |JobManager                    |I| No crashed jobs to re-schedule
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using HTTPS, HTTP and port 8443 should not work. Here is what I get locally when doing so:
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> curl https://localhost:8443/accounting

Apache `OfBiz` uses HTTPS protocol with `8443` port.